# How should I use python requests to upload a HTML file to a Cisco Spark room as an attachment?

Tags: python, python-requests, cisco

I can upload a HTML file as an attachment to a Cisco Spark room using curl:

```
curl -X POST \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" \
    -F "roomId=ROOMID" \
    -F "text=Hello example" \
    -F "files=@/tmp/simple.html;type=text/html" \
    https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages
```

It gets there just fine, with the text and the `simple.html` is there as an attachment as expected. All of the necessary (for Cisco Spark) permissions are set, the ACCESS_TOKEN is good, the roomId is good and the user with this access token has already joined the room.

However, when I try the same using python requests, the message *does* get there, but without the attachment:

```py
resp = requests.post(url='https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages',
                     headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN},
                     data={'roomId': ROOMID, 'text': 'Hello example'},
                     files={'file': ('/tmp/simple.html', open('/tmp/simple.html', 'rb'), 'text/html')})
```

In the `res` response I can see that the message was indeed posted, but did not contain a "files" node - so it *seems* that the requests lib hasn't merged the data and the files?

My `requests.__version__` is `'2.11.1'`, my python is `Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0` and Cisco Spark is whatever version it's at on the day of posting ...

(ps: could someone with enough reputation kindly create the tag 'cisco-spark' and add it to this please?)

Comment: Is it 'file' or 'files' ?

Comment: @t.m.adam it's "files" as per https://developer.ciscospark.com/attachments.html, http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.9.1/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file, and, the curl request that worked above. Your question prompted me to try with "file" anyway but ``TypeError: request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'file'``

Comment: No , i mean the 'file' key in your `files` dict ( in other words the name of the html input )

Comment: Ah ha! That was it :-) All now works well.

Comment: I know, those little details can be very frustrating sometimes..

Answer (score 0):

All credit to @t.m.adam for this:

```
resp = requests.post(url='https://api.ciscospark.com/v1/messages',
                     headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ACCESS_TOKEN},
                     data={'roomId': ROOMID,
                           'text': 'Hello StackOverflow'},
                     files={'files': ('/tmp/simple.html', open('/tmp/simple.html', 'rb'), 'text/html')})
```

Internally (within requests) the keys of the `data` kwarg and the keys of the `files` kwarg are combined, resulting in a multi-part upload where Cisco-Spark then receives a `files`-named form-data.